# Reading __EVENTTARGET causes event is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to use information on which control was clicked for setting up the page. I use this to set up a sortable table in code. I found through this forum that I can use `Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET")` for that. However, as soon as I do something with that parameter, the callback function is no longer called. Is this expected behavior or am I making a mistake?

Here some snippets of my code. The code in Page_Load() is:

```
string sortRequest = Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
bool isCurrentField = false;
if (sortRequest != null) isCurrentField = sortRequest.Contains(header.Field);
if (!isCurrentField)
{
    // Add a hyperlink for sorting to the cell
    LinkButton newLink = new LinkButton();
    newLink.Text = header.Title;
    newLink.Font.Bold = true;
    newLink.ID = "link" + header.Field;
    newLink.CommandName = "Sort";
    newLink.CommandArgument = header.Field;
    newLink.Command += new CommandEventHandler(LinkButton_Command);
    hdrCell.Controls.Add(newLink);
}
else
{
    hdrCell.Text = header.Title;
    hdrCell.Font.Bold = true;
}
```

My callback:

```
public void LinkButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    _sortOrder = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

I have also tried it with copying the sortRequest into a temporary variable, but that doesn't make a difference. As soon as I comment out the line `if (sortRequest != null) isCurrentField = sortRequest.Contains(header.Field);`, the callback is called again.

Comment: Try to read the value of  Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET"); in the Page_PreInit(...) event instead of the Page_Load(...) event.

Comment: Tried this but same result; The callback is not called.

Comment: In my code, I am reading the value of the field like this:
string ctrlname = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET"); Maybe this will work for you

Comment: I tried the Params.Get, but no difference still. There is also no exception on header.Field, as I checked it is never null. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fault in your logic. You have a dynamically created control `LinkButton` with `LinkButton_Command` event handler connected to it. For the server-side event to fire on postback, the control must be present in the page control tree. This means the dynamic `LinkButton` must be created, configured and added to `hdrCell.Controls` always, regardless of `sortRequest` value. Only then will it be able to pick up the fact that it was clicked from the `Request` and fire its `Command` event.

Comment: Of course, you are right! Thank you. I will create the LinkButton in a disabled state instead of leaving it out.